# Haskell - Making Int an instance of my class

Tags: haskell

When I try to make Int an Instance of my class Gueltig by:

```
instance Gueltig Int where
    ist_gueltig (Int a) = Ja
```

, why do I get the error message "Undefined data constructor "Int""?
How do I make instances of Int?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's nothing to pattern-match here. You don't care about the *value* of the integer, just that it *is* an integer. Which is already proven by the compiler before even *choosing* that instance. So, just make it

```
instance Gültig Int where
  istGültig _ = Ja
```

Alternatively you could also write `istGültig a = Ja`, but variables that aren't used should not have names (in fact, `-Wall` will trigger a warning if they do).

OTOH, `Int a` would only be valid if there was a *data type* like

```
data Int = Int {intData :: ???}
```

If fact `Int` [*does* kind of look like this](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-prim-0.5.3/docs/src/GHC.Types.html#Int), but this is a GHC implementation detail:

```
data {-# CTYPE "HsInt" #-} Int = I# Int#
```

Here, `#Int` is a hard-baked machine representation type. It's an *unlifted type*, meaning it behaves in some regards different from standard Haskell values. You don't want to deal with this unless you really know why.

Normally, you should just treat `Int` as an abstract type that can't be further unwrapped or anything. Just use it directly with standard numeric / comparison operators.